# Python pip install doesn't install pynput?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, pynput

When I type

```sh
pip install pynput
```

in the command prompt it just says `collecting pynput` and doesn't install. I have already checked to make sure pip works. I am using Python 3.5.0.

Comment: What exactly happen after you run `pip install`? Terminal hangs? Or it ends without output? Can you add full logs from console after performing install?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade pip

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then Try:

```
python -m pip install pynput
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install pynput from Pypi.
2. Try to type 'pip install pynput' again in the command prompt.

If it still says the same thing, try to update your python.