# Trying to detect mouse clicks

Tags: python, mouseevent

Very baby coder here trying to detect mouse click events.. I don't think any external packages will work for me because my computer is simply too old. My pip and python can't support mouse, pynput, etc. Or at least I can't figure out how to get it to support those modules.. Whenever I try to install pynput or mouse, terminal comes back saying I need to upgrade my pip. When I try to upgrade, it's not going through for some reason. Using python 2.7 and pip 9.0.1 on a 2014 Macbook Air.

I'm trying to detect clicks in a graphwin, just using the Graphics module. Is there anyway to do this without tkinter or pynput or the like?

Thanks!

Comment: "I don't think any external packages will work for me because my computer is simply too old" -- if it can run Python, how old can it be? In any event, it might help if you describe what the problem is in more detail. Clicking on *what*? Outside of a GUI, that doesn't make much sense. But, if you are using a GUI, then it seems that you *are* using some external package (or perhaps the turtle module -- which can handle mouse clicks).

Comment: @JohnColeman made some edits, apologies. Just using the Graphics module, trying to click in a window. I keep having issues upgrading pip which is preventing me from installing pynput or mouse correctly, maybe it's a directory issue?

Comment: If you mean `graphics.py`, it doesn't seem to be very heavily used or maintained, but you can find some [documentation](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~keen/help/Zelle-graphics-reference.pdf) as well as tutorials (google for one that helps). There seem to be two methods, `getMouse()` and `checkMouse()` which might be enough. What it doesn't seem to have is a facility for writing event handlers which react to mouse clicks. I haven't actually used it, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: As far as `pip` and things like `pynput` go, perhaps you could ask another question which focused just on that. If you do so, be explicit about the details such as version number, operating system, error messages, etc. Before you do that, make sure that your question isn't a duplicate. There is a [pip tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) which has over 16,000 questions (most of which seem to be about trouble-shooting it). There is a good chance that one of those questions already provides the answer that you need (e.g. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61048438/4996248))